# how to insert a count record column into an existing table

Tags: insert

I need to count records from one table and insert that YTD total into a table that I am storing YTD summary totals.

Here is what I tried to do:

SELECT COUNT(members) as YTD_Members_CT FROM dbo.tblMembers
 WHERE InputDate between '2011-10-01' and '2012-04-30'

Insert into dbo.YTDSummary (YTD_Members)
values (YTD_Members_CT)

The dbo.tblMembers contains my daily information that I wish to count.  I am trying to store the count of members for the time period in another table.  I can get the count to appear on the screen with a column name "YTD_Members_CT" but how do I get that count to insert into the other table called dbo.YTDSummary

Comment: I would recommend not storing calculated values in your database. If anything changes in the underlying data, you will have to remember to rerun your calculations.  Whereas if you base your outputs on the calculation itself (instead of the persisted value), your outputs are always "live".

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the following Statement:

```
Insert into dbo.YTDSummary (YTD_Members) SELECT COUNT(members) as YTD_Members_CT FROM dbo.tblMembers WHERE InputDate between '2011-10-01' and '2012-04-30';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database engine you are using but it looks like MS-SQL.

You should be able to do this by contenanating the query something like:

```
insert into dbo.YTDSummary (YTD_Members) values ((SELECT COUNT(members) as YTD_Members_CT FROM dbo.tblMembers WHERE InputDate between '2011-10-01' and '2012-04-30'))
```